# How to create alert message in mac os x 10.2?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, alert, appkit

i need create one alert message in mac os x 10.2, but I can not use nsalert, According To nsalert since documentation is available from 10.3 onwards.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [NSRunAlertPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSRunAlertPanel) and others like `NSRunCriticalAlertPanel` or `NSRunInformationalAlertPanel`, for old alert messages.

Comment: This method is *deprecated*